# Run incremental in different warehouse than full refresh

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I would like to build an [incremental model](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models) that utilizes two different warehouse specs depending on whether the incremental or the full-refresh version of the run is occurring.

I was thinking that something like the following might be possible but have not yet been able to make it work:

```
{% if is_incremental() %}
    {{ config(snowflake_warehouse=var("m_warehouse")) }}
{% else %}
    {{ config(snowflake_warehouse=var("xl_warehouse")) }} 
{% endif %}

{{
    config(
        materialized="incremental", 
        unique_key="pk_number", 
        on_schema_change="fail"
    )
}}

-- my model logic
select 1;
```

The answer to this should be a [config block](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-configs) at the top of a model file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can inline the Jinja inside the config block:

```
{{
  config({
    "materialized": "incremental", 
    "unique_key": "pk_number", 
    "on_schema_change": "fail",
    "snowflake_warehouse": var('m_warehouse') if is_incremental() else var('xl_warehouse')
  })
}}
```

Note - More complicated Jinja logic won't work here. There is a PR to allow for overriding the default macro, but it is not yet released: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/pull/503